# Big.js in java not working in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I am using Big.js for  comparing numericvalue in Jsp.its working fine in Mozilla, but when I checked it in IE its not working properly. I have used below Big.js code.Please review it and guide me for same.

I have used this Big.js from `http://github.com/whatgoodisaroad/Big-js`

```
            Big.prototype.lessThanOrEqualTo = function(right) {
            var c = compare(this, right);
            return c == LT || c == EQ;
            };

            function compare(bl, br) {

            bl = bl.clone();
            br = br.clone();

            if (bl.sign != br.sign) {
            if (bl.sign == POSITIVE)                    { return GT; }
            else /* (bl.sign == NEGATIVE) */            { return LT; }
            }

            else if (bl.exponent != br.exponent) {
            if (bl.sign == POSITIVE) {
            if (bl.exponent > br.exponent)          { return GT; }
            else                                    { return LT; }
            }
            else {
            if (bl.exponent > br.exponent)          { return LT; }
            else                                    { return GT; }
            }
            }

            else {
            var same = sameExponent(bl, br);


            return bl.sign == POSITIVE ?
            compareMantissae(same.l.mantissa, same.r.mantissa) :
            compareMantissae(same.r.mantissa, same.l.mantissa);
            }
            }

            // Compare only mantissae, assuming they correspond to equal 
            // exponents:
            function compareMantissae(m1, m2) {

            m1 = m1.slice();
            m2 = m2.slice();


            if (!m2.length) {
            if (mantissaIsZero(m1)) { return EQ; }
            else                    { return GT; }
            }
            else if (!m1.length) {
            if (mantissaIsZero(m2)) { return EQ; }
            else                    { return LT; }
            }

            if (m1[0] > m2[0])          { return GT; }
            else if (m1[0] < m2[0])     { return LT; }

            return compareMantissae(m1.splice(1), m2.splice(1));
            }
```

Comment: What error you have? What did you tried?

Comment: In IE you can press F12 to open the developer tools. In the script tab you can press the "start debugging" button and it should break on any errors (if there are any). If there are not then what exactly isn't working?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't do anything either, if I put that in a page with the big.js code from here: https://github.com/whatgoodisaroad/Big-js/blob/master/build/Big.js there are no errors but that might be because the code as you posted it doesn't do anyting at all. Please specify what is going wrong. I think you are able to edit your post.

Comment: Actually its not giving me any error but i am comparing to numaric value using this Big.js. and when i compare value more then 10 its give me abnormal result like i compare 10 >= 11 its give me true in IE.

Answer (score 0):

```
In Big.js there are compareMantissae() function

function compareMantissae(m1, m2) {
m1 = m1.slice();
m2 = m2.slice();

if (!m2.length) {   
    if (mantissaIsZero(m1)) { return EQ; }
    else                    { return GT; }
}
else if (!m1.length) {
    if (mantissaIsZero(m2)) { return EQ; }
    else                    { return LT; }
}

if (m1[0] > m2[0])          { return GT; }
else if (m1[0] < m2[0])     { return LT; }

// return compareMantissae(m1.splice(1), m2.splice(1));
return compareMantissae(m1.splice(-1*(m1.length-1),(m1.length-1)),m2.splice(-1*(m2.length-1),(m2.length-1)));
}

in this function there are change instead of
// return compareMantissae(m1.splice(1), m2.splice(1));

put this
return compareMantissae(m1.splice(-1*(m1.length-1),(m1.length-1)),m2.splice(-1*(m2.length-1),(m2.length-1)));
its working in IE(6,7,8,9),Mozilla and Chrome also.

this function works like this,
array.splice(index,howmany,item1,.....,itemX);
Parameter
index : Required. An integer that specifies at what position to add/remove items, Use negative values
to specify the position from the end of the array
howmany : Required. The number of items to be removed. If set to 0, no items will be removed
item1, ..., itemX : Optional. The new item(s) to be added to the array
```